# How to display form errors just when input are invalid and dirty?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have working with AngularJS. I have the following form :

```
<html lang="en"  ng-app="app">
...
<div ng-controller="RegisterController">
<h3>Register</h3>

<form name="registerForm" class="form-horizontal panel-body" novalidate="novalidate"> 
<form name="registerForm" class="form-horizontal panel-body" novalidate="novalidate">  

    <div class="form-group">
            <label name="firstname" class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder="First Name"  required>
            </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
            <label name="lastname" class="col-md-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" placeholder="Last Name"  required>
            </div>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
            <label name="email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Your email</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="email"  class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email Address"  required>
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-2">
            <span ng-show="showError(userInfoForm.email, 'email')" ...>
                    You must enter a valid email
                </span>
                <span ng-show="showError(userInfoForm.email, 'required')" ...>
                This field is required
                </span> 
             </div>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-disabled="!canRegister()" ng-click="submit()">Register</button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I have also app.js file which contains configuration and controller code, i just paste the controller code:

```
app.controller('RegisterController', function($scope) {
$scope.getCssClasses = function(ngModelContoller) {
return {
error: ngModelContoller.$invalid && ngModelContoller.$dirty,
success: ngModelContoller.$valid && ngModelContoller.$dirty
};
};
$scope.showError = function(ngModelController, error) {
return ngModelController.$error[error];
};

$scope.canRegister = function() {
return $scope.registerForm.$dirty &&
$scope.registerForm.$valid;
};

});
```

My problem is that when i load the register page ( the page which contains the form), i have the two errors are printed : 
**You must enter a valid email This field is required** 
I am wondering how to do print the error when the input is dirty and invalid and desapear when the input text is valid.
Thansk for your help

Answer (score 0):

Set class "validate" on each input class, and add style.css, like:

```
.validate.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
   border: 2px solid red;
}
.validate.ng-dirty.ng-valid {
   border: 2px solid green;
}
```

`Here is one way (of many) to validate forms`    http://plnkr.co/edit/u0Wr0dza8lGnVrgwrUEa

Answer (score 0):

`$error` is the object of errors where the key is the field validation name and value is the actual error message

```
<input type="email" name="emailName" ng-model="email" required>
```

for this example `myForm.emailName.$error.email = true` if email is not matched with format.
`myForm.emailName.$error.required = true` if you haven't added anyhting in input field

you can check valid or not of the field directly by using `myForm.emailName.$valid` but
the problem in your case is they want to show the user what is the error by having two cases. so they entered into `$error object` to check for the `error is required email or invalid email`

```
1.Email is required.
2.Invalid email address.
```

so they used `$error` object.
this is how myForm.emailName looks:

```
{"$viewValue":"ss","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":false,"$touched":true,"$pristine":false,"$dirty":true,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"email":true},"$name":"emailName","$options":null}
```

[check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_validate)